# Generating sounds without a library?

Tags: c++, c, audio

I am trying to find documentation, tutorials, examples on how to generate sounds. I mean without using a library that will hide all the interesting stuff.

I am interesting in sound and I want to start doing something with it but I don't know from where to start.

Correct me if I am wrong but the lowest level to generate sound is one of these (DirectSound
,CoreAudio,ALSA,OSS) depending on the OS. So I have to pick an operating system and learn the appropriate sound system?

Is this really worth or I should just learn a library that wraps all the above and offers cross platform compatibility?

Maybe this question is not very clear and I am sorry for that but as it turned out I don't even know what I want. I am just trying to find something interesting for my thesis.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, except that it is an interesting factoid about a musician who made sound with a computer that wasn't built to make sound: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphex_Twin#ZX81_competition

Comment: @AlexReynolds That's inspiring.

Comment: If you just want "a" sound, just do `cout << (char)7;` :)

Comment: @Mysticial: I think that's more of an A#, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB The BIOS beep is an A#? I thought that was implementation dependent?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. Even OSes are libraries ;-) And if no OS is used, we would need to know your exact hardware, and it would come down to: write a device driver for... which is likely too broad. SDL version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110905/simple-wave-generator-with-sdl-in-c/36550306#36550306

Comment: "Even OSes are libraries"?  I guess the question wasn't very specific about "the interesting stuff", but I suspect you missed the point they were going for.  It's quite common in exploratory programming to try doing things "without a library" -- using only the base components provided by your development platform.  Anyway, they specified the general level of abstraction of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started.

```
// filename "wf.cpp" (simple wave-form generator)

   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <stdint.h>

int main()
   {

   const double R=8000; // sample rate (samples per second)
   const double C=261.625565; // frequency of middle-C (hertz)
   const double F=R/256; // bytebeat frequency of 1*t due to 8-bit truncation (hertz)
   const double V=127; // a volume constant

   for ( int t=0; ; t++ )
      {
      uint8_t temp = (sin(t*2*M_PI/R*C)+1)*V; // pure middle C sine wave
   // uint8_t temp = t/F*C; // middle C saw wave (bytebeat style)
   // uint8_t temp = (t*5&t>>7)|(t*3&t>>10); // viznut bytebeat composition
      std::cout<<temp;
      }

   }
```

compile and run on Linux via **ALSA** interface:

```
make wf && ./wf |aplay
```

compile and run on Linux via **GStreamer** interface:

```
make wf && ./wf |gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/dev/stdin ! 'audio/x-raw-int,rate=8000,channels=1,depth=8' ! autoaudiosink
```

[GStreamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) claims to be cross-platform.  It's main feature of interest is that you can create (or use existing) plugins to construct a pipeline of audio filters.

Comment: My example uses 8-bit mono, but it can easily be modified to use other formats (for example 16-bit stereo).

Comment: Play a CD: `find /run/user/${USER}/gvfs/cdd* -iname "*.wav" -print0 |xargs -0 aplay`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538768/6764

Comment: That gstreamer example didn't work for me in 2021, here it is translated for gstreamer 1.0: `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/dev/stdin ! 'audio/x-raw,format=U8,rate=8000,channels=1,depth=8' ! alsasink`

Answer (score 5):

On some Unix(ish) systems, you can [just write audio data to `/dev/audio` (or `/dev/dsp`)](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Sound-HOWTO/x504.html) and it will play.  On modern Linux systems using ALSA, you may need to pipe it to [`aplay`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay) instead.  In either case, though, you don't need to use any specific sound library — just open an output stream and write to it.  This is how all those [bytebeat](http://canonical.org/~kragen/bytebeat/) one-liners do it.

Comment: +1. Great overview of bytebeaters here: http://www.metafilter.com/tags/bytebeat

Answer (score 2):

You need to comunicate with the audio hardware, but the times in which you can do it directly are long over...

May i suggest [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal)?

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers just suggest some abstraction or library. There's always the possiblity to fall back directly on the hardware. (Whether this is a good idea is a completely different question and completely up to you to decide)

May I suggest looking at audio driver code? The [Emu10k1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emu10k1/) driver is just one example available in linux sources.

Also worth a look is this: "[Creating a Kernel Driver for the PC-Speaker](http://linuxgazette.net/issue69/mathew.html)"

I also remember the days on Amiga where some funny dude created a program that (ab-)used the [Floppy drive stepper motor as an audio output](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=amiga%20floppy%20stepper%20audio&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT0JOIPxyE8&ei=iKovT_rzIoPChAfki93jCg&usg=AFQjCNGQ-m5raZR-L1MdPH-51guqCioZWQ&sig2=E7Tt45Lk_iSbIZDF9XSKHg&cad=rja).